# Using Win32 handles with DLLs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dll, handle

I have a piece of equipment that I would like to control from within Matlab on WinXP32. Its APIs are packaged in a DLL with an associated C header.

The device's API functions rely on a hardware descriptor, which is accessed by its Win32 handle and can only be directly manipulated by the API functions. From the "foo.h" header provided by the manufacturer:

```
typedef HANDLE BAR
#ifdef _DLL_EXPORT
    #define _DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define _DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

This handle is then used by the API functions, whose C signatures are of the form:

```
FOO_RETURN Device_Init(BAR *pbar, DWORD parameter1, ....)
```

Moving to Matlab, I load the library:

```
loadlibrary('foo','foo.h');
```

and the API functions are now available in Matlab. In libfunctionsview, their signatures look like:

```
Name         Arguments
Device_Init  (voidPtr, uint32, ....)
```

and the "foo.m" function created by loadlibrary describes them as:

```
fcns.name{fcnNum}='Device_Init'; fcns.calltype{fcnNum}='stdcall'; fcns.LHS{fcnNum}="uint32'; fcns.RHS{fcnNum}={'errorPtr, 'uint32', ...)
```

My problem is this handle "BAR". None of the following are accepted:

```
pbar = libpointer('BAR');  % Type was not found
pbar = libstruct('BAR');   % Undefined function or variable 'lib.BAR'
pbar = libpointer;         % Segfaults when passed to DLL
```

Is there a way to create and manage this handle "BAR" in Matlab so that it can be used in Matlab calls to calllib('foo','command',pbar,....) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code to create the MATLAB pointers:

```
pbar = libpointer('voidPtr',[ uint8('some string') 0])
pparameter1 = libpointer('uint32',0)
```

and to call your DLL function use the following command:

```
calllib('foo','Device_Init',pbar,pparameter1,...)
```